# jQuery/javascript dynamic hasClass condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a special condition where there are several divs with/without ***XXX*-personalized-product** class. The ***XXX*** is dynamic. I couldn't figure out how to check if the div having xxx-personalized-product class is clicked or not. Something like:

```
if(jQuery('.containers').hasClass('*-personalized-product')){
    //do my stuff
}
```

Anyone has an idea ?
FYI, I cannot run a loop of .containers since there are several hundreds of them which slows the performance.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `jQuery('.containers').is('[class$="-personalized-product]"')` try using jQuery's `is()` function

Comment: Why not add an extra class that they all share in common? ex. `.p-p`. BTW if you are really worried about performance, the `XXX-` pattern could be an id instead. Once an id is found the process stops, unlike a search for a class which will essentially stop once everything has been searched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the selector string `.containers[class*="-personalized-product"]`:

```js
if ($(`.containers[class*="-personalized-product"]`).length) {
  console.log('doing stuff');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="containers foo-personalized-product"></div>
```

```js
if ($(`.containers[class*="-personalized-product"]`).length) {
  console.log('doing stuff');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="containers not-personalized"></div>
```

The `[class*="-personalized-product"]` checks for whether the element has `-personalized-product` anywhere in its `class` attribute string.

If you already have a jQuery collection that you want to check whether it has an element matching that selector, use `.is` instead, eg:

```
if ($containers.is(`[class*="-personalized-product"]`)) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you @CertainPerformance for explaining all these with examples. **if($containers.is(`[class*="-personalized-product"]`))** worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(jQuery('.containers').is('[class$="-personalized-product"]')){
    //do my stuff
}
```

`$=` will select only elements having a class ending with `-personalized-product`

Comment: A problem with `$` is that the elements have multiple classes, both `containers` and (possibly) `something-personalized-product`, at least, so `*` will be more reliable

Comment: IMO `jQuery('.containers')` would take care of `.containers` so thought of `$`, it should work

Comment: Thank you @AkashShrivastava for such prompt answer. Your solution also worked, however, the one I chose as answer has some more information and explanations. I'm upvoting your answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Give them a `personalized-product` class as well.

Class names are atomic opaque strings.  If you're trying to match or slice them in any way, that's a sign you should try some other approach.